# Black texture on model (Possible UV issue or glitch)

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view, texture-coordinates

So I'm having a bit of a problem with a model, after opening up the file (imported) it shows up black all over the model except for the eyes and mouth. I assume this is some sort of UV issue, if I attempt to look at the model from afar it looks like there's overlapping UVs or textures but I can't seem to find anything of the sort.

Any tips?

[image]

Seen from afar:
[image]

Update:

[image]

[image]

**My solution is now posted bellow.**

Comment: I think I failed to include the textures in since they show up pink on the pasteall.org. Maybe I should just send away the folder?

Comment: Alright, by the way I just got an update, seems the textures are inverted (that's why they show up black on the outside and glitchy when seen from afar). How can I invert them? (Quite the noobish question I'm aware but I'm still learning up how to work textures on Blender.)

Comment: Sent the file to the pasteall.org . I'll post some more screenshots above, also in better words the outside of the texture is on the inside of the model.

Comment: oh ok yes, so your clothes have thickness, and the outter part is put on a black part of the texture while the inner is put on the colored part, maybe it happened because your face normals were inverted when you baked the Diffuse, do you have a previous version of your object?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bought model, meaning I already got it like this. Is there a way to invert the face models?

Comment: Face normals I mean*

Comment: I don't think it will change anything if you invert the faces normal now, I'm wondering if something can be done, weird that it was sold like this

Comment: Yeah... I'll try researching a bit, if you think of something please let me know. \o

Comment: You can quickly select and delete the parts you want as there are some seams all along, just press L when your cursor is over the area, make sure that the Seam option is selected in the Operator box (bottom left), then X to delete. Now you need to make sure that it leaves a correct mesh

Comment: Then if you want to add some thickness to some parts, give them a Solidify modifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

1. Changing the Render engine from *Cycles* to *EEVEE*.

[image]

2. Select the various affected model components.
3. Proceed to the Material Properties tab
4. Select each individual material and on *Settings*, change the Blend Mode to *Opaque* and turn on *Backface Culling*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your meshes have thickness, the outer parts are black and the inner parts are correctly unwrapped and colored.

There might be another way but a way to fix your problem is to select the black parts with <kbd>L</kbd>. It's easy as they are separate by some seams (make sure that you've activated the *Seam* option in the *Operator* box). Then delete with <kbd>X</kbd>.

If you want to give thickness back to these parts give them a *Solidify* modifier.

Comment: I'd suspect that the model was designed with an outlining technique.  The outer parts are probably supposed to have inward facing normals and be used with backface culling (or some variation of that.)

Comment: so in what way are these outer parts useful?

Comment: Indeed it's related to the backface culling, messed around with those settings and progress has been made! The textures are now back to normal (also changed to Eevee.) I'll update this with the solution in a moment.

Comment: @moonboots See idea 3 of piegames's answer at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69971/how-do-you-add-a-thin-outline

Comment: @Nathan aah ok thank you