# Outline a model Tron style

Tags: materials

I'm trying to make a Tank model for a Tron fan game but I'm new to Blender and I'm having a really hard time outlining the model. I've tried adding a texture to it where I exported the UV map and then sorta outlined that, but it looked really terrible. It was either pixelly and blurry or the angles were all wrong or the size of the outline was wonky depending on where on the mesh it was. I feel like this should be really easy, and I must be just doing something wrong. I've attached an image of the current model (I'm starting with just the gun so I can get a workflow down) and the general desired outcome.

Edit: To clarify, I need the model to be exportable with the outlines to be used in Godot. I'm using the gltf/glb renderer.

[image] [image]

Comment: For game assets, you'll want to look into the [inverted hole method](https://youtu.be/voF6VlJ0mPI) and [square uvs](https://youtu.be/okB8EUxPTKs) like Arc System Works games use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you add a thin outline?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69971/how-do-you-add-a-thin-outline)

Answer (score 1):

There are many options within blender to get an outline, such as through the material editor, freestyle, or Grease Pencil (as mentioned in other answers). However, these options typically will not be exportable to be used within game engines.

When creating outlines, the best option is usually to use the material editor or post-processing in whatever game engine your are using. This would be far more reusable as well, as it can be applied globally to the game/models rather than you having to manually setup glowing in Blender for each model you make.

If for some reason the glow effect has to be done 100% in Blender (which I don't recommend), you could possibly try baking out a black & white texture that highlights where the sharp corners of the model are (with the sharp corners becoming the outline). You can get this texture by baking a pointiness/curvature map (there's lots of tutorials online regarding this, so I won't recap the process here for brevity). Then in your game engine of choice, you could plug this map into the emission input of a material.

Comment: The glow itself I can handle in Godot. I tried getting the engine to make an outline automatically, but it doesn't really get the effect that I want/need. I'll look into the curvature map, as baking the outline on to the mesh seems to garner the best result (and be the least resource intensive). Thank you!